# Data Subset in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and I wish to divide it to 2 separate sets. I know that using `train_test_split` from `sklearn.cross_validation`, one can divide the data in two sets (train and test). However, I couldn't find any solution about splitting the data into validation and sample subsets.

I would like to subset my data into 80% sample set and 20% validation set. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by sample set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sample 80% of your dataframe:

```
df.sample(.8)
```

and for remaining 20%:

```
ss = df.sample(.8)
val = df.loc[[x for x in df.index if x not in ss.index], :]
```

However the train_test split shuffle the data while separating and you do not need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you mean by a sample set, if you're wanting to simply split the dataset up into two parts, `train_test_split` will work just fine, just a df with a different name.

IF however you are meaning you're trying to divide the dataset into 3 parts, a train, test, and validation set, then I have to share this function I found a while back that has been fantastic to keep in my backpacker.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
 
def train_test_val(df_input, stratify_colname='y',
                                         frac_train=0.6, frac_val=0.15, frac_test=0.25,
                                         random_state=None):
    '''
    Splits a Pandas dataframe into three subsets (train, val, and test)
    following fractional ratios provided by the user, where each subset is
    stratified by the values in a specific column (that is, each subset has
    the same relative frequency of the values in the column). It performs this
    splitting by running train_test_split() twice.
 
    Parameters
    ----------
    df_input : Pandas dataframe
        Input dataframe to be split.
    stratify_colname : str
        The name of the column that will be used for stratification. Usually
        this column would be for the label.
    frac_train : float
    frac_val   : float
    frac_test  : float
        The ratios with which the dataframe will be split into train, val, and
        test data. The values should be expressed as float fractions and should
        sum to 1.0.
    random_state : int, None, or RandomStateInstance
        Value to be passed to train_test_split().
 
    Returns
    -------
    df_train, df_val, df_test :
        Dataframes containing the three splits.
    '''
 
    if frac_train + frac_val + frac_test != 1.0:
        raise ValueError('fractions %f, %f, %f do not add up to 1.0' % \
                         (frac_train, frac_val, frac_test))
 
    if stratify_colname not in df_input.columns:
        raise ValueError('%s is not a column in the dataframe' % (stratify_colname))
 
    X = df_input # Contains all columns.
    y = df_input[[stratify_colname]] # Dataframe of just the column on which to stratify.
 
    # Split original dataframe into train and temp dataframes.
    df_train, df_temp, y_train, y_temp = train_test_split(X,
                                                          y,
                                                          stratify=y,
                                                          test_size=(1.0 - frac_train),
                                                          random_state=random_state)
 
    # Split the temp dataframe into val and test dataframes.
    relative_frac_test = frac_test / (frac_val + frac_test)
    df_val, df_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(df_temp,
                                                      y_temp,
                                                      stratify=y_temp,
                                                      test_size=relative_frac_test,
                                                      random_state=random_state)
 
    assert len(df_input) == len(df_train) + len(df_val) + len(df_test)
 
    return df_train, df_val, df_test
```